# Password-Protect a Single Page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, password-protection

I have a very simple Rails 4.2.4 app that doesn't have or need users. I would, however, like to password-protect a single page (an admin page) which happens to be the index view. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this line to the top of the controller and it works:

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "your_name", :password => "your_password", only: :index
```